# Find whether an Image is used anywhere

Tags: php, silverstripe

In my SilverStripe 3.4 environment I have a bunch of different models that have an attached Image, e.g.:

- `BlogPost` `has_one` `Image` (via silverstripe/blog)
- `Widget` `has_one` `Image` (via silverstripe/widgets)
- `MyWidget` `has_one` `Image` (custom module)

I want to prevent an Image e.g. ID 123 from being deleted in the CMS admin if it's used in any of the above (as examples - this should be system wide).

Is there a way that I can check all models that have a related Image at once, maybe via a `Image belongs_many_many` lookup or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd prob need to decorate `Image` via a `DataExtension` subclass and declare a `$belongs_to` static array with a custom `onBeforeDelete()` or possibly `validate()`.

Regardless, within either is where you'd call a routine that checks your database for the necessary conditions. Your choice of which method to use
is dictated by the scenarios under which an `Image` record might be deleted in your system (e.g you may have some automated, non-Human tasks where the scenario you wish to avoid is played out - so you'd avoid `validate()` and use `onBeforeDelete()`)

Something *like* this (Totally untested!)

```
class MyImageExtension extends DatExtension
{

    public function onBeforeDelete()
    {
        if (!$this->imagesExistThatShouldNotBeDeleted()) {
            parent::onBeforeDelete();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean True if images exist that shouldn't be deleted, false otherwise.
     */
    private function imagesExistThatShouldNotBeDeleted()
    {
        $owner = $this->getOwner();
        $dataObjectSubClasses = ClassInfo::getValidSubClasses('DataObject');
        $classesWithImageHasOne = [];
        foreach ($dataObjectSubClasses as $subClass) {
            if ($classHasOneImage = $subClass::create()->hasOneComponent('Image')) {
                $classesWithImageHasOne[] = $classHasOneImage;
            }
        }

        if (in_array($owner->class, $classesWithImageHasOne)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Russell. Assuming I don't know how many models will have an Image related, can I achieve this using the same concept as you've described, or would I need to be aware of all relations for this approach to work?

Comment: I have updated the "solution" as per your question. Note: The solution above assumes the `Image` has_one's for all classes that have one, are called `Image`. If you have subclassed `Image` then you'll need to modify the call to `DataObject::hasOneComponent()` using `in_array()` for example.

Comment: You can't prevent deletion by not calling `parent::onBeforeDelete();`. Doing this in a `DataExtension` has no effect whatsoever. Even doing this in the class itself would be bad, as it will raise a "broken onBeforeDelete" error. I think it would be better to override the `canDelete` permission instead? Or throw an error in `onBeforeDelete` if you want to go hardcore.

Comment: Yeah just re-looked and you're absolutely correct. Regardless of throwing an error (exception surely?) or using canDelete(), both will result in a 500 or 403 HTTP status code respectively, so will need to be handled regardless,